# I want to reverse and return an array in a function in system verilog, i tried below code and i am getting following error

Tags: system-verilog

```
module rev_array;
initial
 begin
 int array_in[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 typedef integer array[9:0];
 function array reverse(int array_in[10]);
 array reverse;
 for(integer i=0;i<$size(array_in)-1;i++)
  begin
    for(int j=$size(array_in)-1;j>=0;j--)
    begin     
     reverse[j]=array_in[i];
    end
  end 
return reverse;
endfunction:reverse

  reverse(array_in);
  for(integer k=0;k<$size(array_in)-1;k++)
  begin
  $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, reverse[k]);      
  end  
end
endmodule
```

For the above code, I am getting error
Error-[SE] Syntax error
  Following verilog source has syntax error :
  "testbench.sv", 7: token is 'function'
    function array reverse(int array_in[10]);

I want to return an array named reverse(same name as the function ) which has 10 elements, each element being an integer, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please don't edit you code and then ask a completely different question. Please ask a new question instead. The idea of Stack Overflow is not only to help the original asker of the question, but also to provide a useful resource for future Googlers. By radically editing your question, you make it useless for future Googlers. Both questions are good questions and so both may be useful to future Googlers on their own. (Your edits are not lost - you can click on `edited` and copy and paste them into a new question.) With you edit in place, Dave's original answer makes no sense to future Googlers.

Comment: Sure Matthew, thanks for correcting, I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a function in the middle of a procedural block. Move it to the top level of the module. You have many other problems. Note there is a built-in reverse array method.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried moving the function out of the initial block at the top of the module, but in that case I am getting this error now  in $display line in the code
Error-[IUS] Illegal use of scope
testbench.sv, 26
rev_array, "rev_array.reverse"
 Scope cannot be used in this context;                                                                                To return the reverse array do i need to do return reverse at the end of the function  or will it automatically return the name of the function ? I want to return a fixed size array named reverse which has 10 int type elements

Comment: You can use the name of the function as the return variable. Do not not declare it separately, and no need to use the `return` statement. Alternatively, you can declare another variable and return that - like one does in most other programming languages.

Comment: Okay sure but when I do so in the above code I still get error in the $display line where I am trying to print reverse array after calling reverse function in the initial block...while I wrote function definition in the top module like you directed ..-->  Error-[IUS] Illegal use of scope testbench.sv, 26 rev_array, "rev_array.reverse" Scope cannot be used in this context

Comment: Can you edit an update to your original question and show what your code looks like now?

Comment: I updated the code, could you please take a look now ? I am able to see the reversed array inside the function by printing it but when I try to print it using $display outside the function, I think it is not being returned properly somehow, in the 4th line from end, getting errorError-[IUS] Illegal use of scope testbench.sv, 26 rev_array, "rev_array.reverse" Scope cannot be used in this context

Error- Illegal bit select testbench.sv, 26 Error is found in following cross-module reference, illegal bit select on the target. Source info: $display("reverse[%0d]:%0d", k, rev_array.reverse[k]);

Comment: You are not assigning the output of the `reverse` function to anything.